# Texpad IOS Keyboard

Tags: texpad

I am using Texpad on my Ipad and would like to use the texpad keyboard.
It is written: "Texpad comes with two keyboards, you can choose between them by using the editor preferences."

I cannot find these preferences. I can only change colors and fonts...

Can anybody help?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: I think it has been removed in recent versions. Now you just have extra keys (with some of the functionalities of the old texpad keyboard)

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/math/comments/74edlu/mqkb_true_math_keyboard_for_ios_beta_testers/